# how to set DB selected value to select tag in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

Hi i am stuck from this issue

```
<form:select path = "mapUser" name="userTypeV"   class="form-control" >
                                                <form:option value = "NONE" label = "-- Please Select One --"/>
                                                <form:options items = "${mapUser}"  />
```

It's working well but i have one doubt how to set DB selected value to this tag.

Comment: What do mean by "DB selected value"

Comment: I am using oracle DB and i have String value like "G" then ui side how i set selected value in select tag   This code like this one '<select name="userTypeV" class="form-control">
 <option value="NONE">-- Please Select One --</option>
 <option value="C">Consultant</option><option value="G">Admin User</option><option value="L">LogIn User</option><option value="S">Staff</option>
 </select>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `<form:select>` tag you must put in the path the name of the bean attribute will keep the id of the selected item.

In **form:options tag**:

1. items: the bean attribute containing the list of selectable items
2. itemLabel: the description to be shown in the dropbox
3. itemValue: the field to be saved (usually id) in the path of the

For your problems, possible solutions

***Solution 1:*** if MapUser is list of User objects

```
class User{

 private String id; //  For e.g. C
 private String value; // For e.g. Consultant
}

List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
users.add(new User("C", "Consultant"));
users.add(new User("G", "AdminUser"));
users.add(new User("L", "LogInUser"));
users.add(new User("S", "Staff"));

<form:select path="mapUser" class="form-control">
    <form:option value="NONE" label="--Please Select One--" />
    <form:options items="${mapUser}" itemLabel="value" itemValue="id" />
</form:select>
```

***Solution 2:*** if MapUser is Map

```
Map<String, String> users = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
users.put("C", "Consultant");
users.put("G", "AdminUser");
users.put("L", "LogInUser");
users.put("S", "Staff");

<form:select path="mapUser" class="form-control">
    <form:option value="NONE" label="--Please Select One--" />
    <form:options items="${mapUser}"/>
</form:select>
```

Comment: Hi yogi thank for your solution but i am previously done this one but i am struggle how to show the selected value from the list. Your code only show the number list only and how do ishow initial value like AdminUser.